# hive basic group by and over(partition by ) function encountered a bug

Tags: mysql, hadoop, group-by, hive

```
select
    day,
    count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY day) as cnt
from a.table_b
where day between '2017-10-13' and '2017-10-14';
```

the result of this query are shown below:

```
day        cnt
2017-10-13  12
2017-10-13  12
2017-10-14  13
2017-10-14  13
```

however,when using group by to group this result,

```
select day, cnt
from 
(
    select day, count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY day) as cnt 
    from a.table_b 
    where day between '2017-10-13' and '2017-10-14'
) t
group by day, cnt;
```

here are result:

```
2017-10-13  1
2017-10-14  1
```

this result are obviously wrong,is this a bug or the wrong usage?

Comment: I don't think you second result set is correct.  I think you should be getting back two records, `2017-10-13 12` and `2017-10-14 13`.  But in any case, this result set is to be expected AFAIK.

Comment: i have correct a error at day between, the result i expected were 2017-10-13 12 and 2017-10-14 13, however, the result missed 12 and 13.

Comment: I really don't see how that could be happening.  But in any case, you should edit your question and tell us what you are trying to do with the second query.

Answer (score 0):

why unnecessary **OVER(PARTITION BY** just use GROUP BY.

```
select
    day,
    count(*) as cnt
from a.table_b
where day between '2017-10-13' and '2017-10-14'
group by  day;
```

Comment: it's not a Serious technical problem, i kown what you mean. i just post a possible bug in hive, i think the logical and usage of my hive code are correct, but it encountered an unexpected result.
and last, i hope you not take the 'why use this' question, i just wanna to discuss why the result encountered. thank you!

Comment: no it is not a bug  count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY day) will behave same in any ANSI data base ...  http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql

Comment: sorry, but,  the behave same is not an answer for me to understand. can you bexplain more specific? and i don't find an answer in your given blogs.

Comment: what this is ANSI  standard behavior what else you want.